# Is there a way to send sensor data from a Samsung Gear S3 watch(e.g. heart rate data) to a smartwatch app(react native or Ionic app) via bluetooth?

Tags: javascript, react-native, bluetooth, tizen, samsung-gear

I am trying to find a way to send a bunch of sensor data from a Tizen smartwatch app to a smartphone using Bluetooth.
I have built the Tizen app for a Samsung Gear S3 werable using the web API but I'm stuck on how to communicate with mobile devices.

Currently I'm savng all the sensor data in an Indexed DB and I would like to sync with an app on the user's phone where I can access the data and process it.

I have looked into the Samsung Accessory Protocol (SAP) API but it seems to only support android phones and I want a solution that works on iOs devices too.
See here for more details:
http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/tech-doc/gear-app-limitation-iphone

Is there a way to send data via bluetooth from the Samsung Gear S3 to an iphone and an android phone and if yes what can I use to achieve this? I am looking into using react native or Ionic to build my smartphone app, but I cannot figure out how to establish a way to receive bluetooth data from the Gear S3.

Any help or resource that can point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BLE** Communication could be an option to communicate between three platforms (Tizen, Android ,iOS). I've shared some relevant Info on these posts:

[This is possible get training and pulse data from Samsung Gear3 to native app for iOS /iPhone ?](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=309046&startId=zzzzz)

[Subscribe BLE](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/subscribe-ble)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it a bit more, it looks like it can be used in my case.